# How should a numbered list be punctuated within dialogue?

Tags: grammaticality, dialogue

In a story, a character reads aloud a numbered list. What should the punctuation be?  I was thinking of treating it like a recitation of a poem or song - indented and italicized. There are 26 items in the list, so it makes sense to leave it as a list rather than write it all out in a paragraph.

Comment: Dialogue (spoken words) is always inline. So, you can't use a vertical list inside quotation marks in this context. You could describe it in narrative (*he read the following list to her*), but if you're going to write actual dialogue, it should to be in actual sentences inside one or more paragraphs.

Comment: As for what that would be, there is no rule. I'm partial to the following: *(1) something. (2) something else.* The implication is that the character would actually say "One [pause] something. Two [pause] something else," and, like other punctuation marks, the parentheses are not actually said.

Comment: If each is more than a word or two you can use one paragraph for each. Open the "speech marks" at the start of each paragraph, but only close them after the final paragraph. In [this example](http://baxtercommunications.nl/quotation-marks-multi-paragraph-rule/) the author has included unquoted bullet points, which looks a little strange to me. IMO an opening quote and an em-dash would look better.